# Angular js adding template to the page with data fetched asynchronously from the server

Tags: ajax, angularjs, asynchronous

I have the template bookTemp.html:

```
<div ng-repeat="book in books">
    <div class="foo" ng-include src="'app/templates/book.html'"></div>
</div>
```

in my index.html file I have its container div:

```
<div ng-include src="'app/templates/bookTemp.html'" ng-controller='BookController'></div>
```

and the controller BookController code is:

```
app.controller("BookController", function($scope, $http, $compile){
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Accept = 'application/json';
    var responsePromise = $http.get('http://localhost:8080/books');

    responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.books= data;
        //do something
    });
    responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("AJAX failed!");
    });
}
```

to fetch the books' data from the server using Ajax request.

Mt question is: 
what is the best practice to populate the template with the "books" data and add it to the page.
The way it is written now no book is shown because the request is asynchronized and so when the template is rendered there is no books' data in the $scope because the request hasn't returned yet.

Should I write a whole directive to do that or instead "load" or use $compile in some way to add it to the page once the request returns successfully (in the line where it says "do something").

I've tried some thing of this kind:

```
var htmlcontent = $('.bookscontainer');
htmlcontent.load('app/templates/bookTemp.html', $scope.articles, someCallback);
```

and also:

```
var htmlcontent = $('.bookscontainer');
htmlcontent.load('app/templates/bookTemp.html'
$compile(htmlcontent.contents())($scope);
```

but it didn't work.

thanks.

Edit:
thanks a lot ExpertSystem.
your code made me realize the problem is some where else.
it turns out that the path of the different templates in the "src" attribute was wrong.
I've changed it to prefix with "." to get the base url and add full path (with in the app) after wards. 
If any one knows of a better practice I would be happy to learn.

Comment: `ngRepeat` watches over `books`, so as soon as it changes it should modify the DOM accordingly. Your code seems looks good to me. It's strange it's not working...

Comment: Seems to be **[working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/T5Jwg/4/)**...

Comment: Even when asynchronously resolving templates (long after the books-data has been fetched), it still **[seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/T5Jwg/5/)**.